# How to avoid neccessity to re-enter password during schell script execution

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, passwords, ssh-agent

I am working on a shell script performing recurring tasks of

- git commit
- git push
- mvn release:prepare
- mvn release:perform

in a couple of paths of a JAVA software project.

Now each of these commands asks for my rsa token password at least once, sometimes even multiple times: "Enter passphrase for key /..../.ssh/id_rsa:"

Is there a way to get around this? It would be OK if I had to enter the password once per script execution.

One boundary condition: I cannot use "spawn, expect, send"

A complication: I run the script in a CENTOS7 shell which is called on a windows10 machine via X-Win32. I would not like to log on to the native Linux Desktop environment.

Note: this is a copy of the same question which I posted in askubuntu - which was an off topic (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178707/how-to-avoid-neccessity-to-re-enter-password-during-schell-script-execution)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh-agent`.

It's quite possible that you already have it running on your system.
Try adding your key to the agent using this command:

```
ssh-add
```

If `ssh-agent` is not running you will get the following message:
"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

To fix that use:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Then run the `ssh-add` command again.

Here is the [ssh agent manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-agent.1).